# F# remove a certain element in an Array

Tags: f#

I've looked in F# array module but it seems like there is no function that could remove a certain element from an array. I was just wondering if there exists any function that does so?

E.g.

```
remove 2 [| 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 |]
val it -> [| 0 ; 1 ; 3 ; 4 |]
```

**UPDATE**

Array filter is what I'm looking for. In addition to that, just a bit more specific with my case though.

If the array I have is not a normal type array but an array of a-specific-class's references. Assuming that I want to remove only element whose `member.order = 2`, then how would the predicate be?

Comment: Since you appear to be doing this course: http://undergraduate.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS3242/ is there a reason you haven't asked your lecturer?

Comment: Because these are all dumb questions, and I tend to ask these questions quite often - saving interesting questions for him anyway. How did you know?

Comment: Your questions looked suspiciously homework-like and there aren't that many F# courses.  Also, you should be able to figure out the lambda yourself.

Answer (score 11):

You may achieve this using F# `Array` module function [Array.filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353840.aspx), as below:

```
> [| 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 |] |> Array.filter ((<>)2);;
val it : int [] = [|0; 1; 3; 4|]
```

UPDATE: It is not hard to figure out what should be the lambda. To make it a bit less dull, you may obtain the same result with another single function [Array.choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370619.aspx):

```
Array.choose (fun x -> if x.order = 2 then None else Some(x))
```

Also let me point out that both functions address a slightly different *dumb* question: remove from an array **all** elements satisfying a condition. Literally your question may be read as removing only **first** occurrence of the element. Such reading still gives you a chance for *creative* contribution to your homework :)

Comment: That's great. Would you mind seeing my update, just a bit more specific about my case?

Comment: @user2431438 `Array.filter (fun x -> x.order <> 2)`