# Is there an exposed function for removing an item from a list?

Tags: list, f#

Is there an exposed function for removing an item from a list?

I do not see any operation for removing an item from a list.

I'm sure I can implement this functionality on my own. However, I kind of expected this operation to be supported in FSharp.Core.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I understand, functional languages uses immutable (read-only) data. So, instead removing element you should create new list and filter undesired elements.

Comment: `List.filter` with a negation?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko That's what I implemented with pattern matching. I just expect that to be included in the framework.

Comment: Thanks MarkSeemann. That's exactly what I was looking for. You can post it as the answer for credit.

Comment: It's not in the standard library because it's not often legitimately needed; what's idiomatic in imperative languages often isn't in functional languages. May I ask what functionality you are going for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# remove a certain element in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628749/f-remove-a-certain-element-in-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - the library designers didn't think it warranted inclusion.

Designing a library of any sort, but in particular a core library like collection modules in F#, is always about finding the right balance between complexity and usefulness. You have to carefully consider if your new feature brings enough to the table to offset the cost of having a larger library.

For removing all instances of an item, you can use `List.filter` with a negated predicate. The designers could have included a `List.remove` function that does the negation internally. It's not something unthinkable, in fact Lisps tend to have both `filter` and `remove`. In Haskell and OCaml, you only have `filter` though - and F# designers probably followed suit here.

If you want to remove only a single instance of an item, you have to write something yourself. This is a somewhat non-standard use case for a list - lists are "about" accumulating elements in sequence; removing particular elements from the middle of the list (as opposed to removing the head or removing all undesirable elements) is seldom useful. If your focus is on adding or removing elements without a need to preserve order, sets or maps (used as multisets) are a better fit for job.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean creating a new list with some items removed based on their value, then you could do this:

```
[1; 2; 3; 1] |> List.filter ((<>) 1)

// Returns [2; 3]
```

This uses the `<>` (not equal) operator in prefix mode by wrapping it in parentheses and then currying it by only providing the first argument.

Note that all instances of this value are excluded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would expect this. For example the same functionality (AFAIK) is not available for Arrays in C#.

However if you want you can use the generic List:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let xs = [1..3]
let xs' = List(xs)
xs'.Remove(2)
xs' 
//val it : List<int> = seq [1; 3]
```

The Generic List has `.Remove`, `.RemoveAt` and `.RemoveAll` methods.